# Converting a large app to SPA

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, single-page-application

Are there any best practices for building a larger app as an SPA ? I am dealing with something that currently has 50 views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dove has a good point, a SPA with 50 views sounds very large, and there probably isn't a silver bullet to convert your app.

A few approaches worth spiking/investigating...

- Seperate your 50 views into application areas. Then use ASP.Net MVC Views & WebAPI to push down the manifest+scaffold to create your views.

  - Use [JSViews+JSRender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/index.html)/[KendoUI](http://kendoui.com)+[KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) to build things up on the client using the manifest/scaffold.
- It's very very new, but why not check out [TypeScript](http://typescript.codeplex.com/) for building the application in JavaScript

Also, look at the 50 views, and see if you can find a smarter way to provide the same functionality, but in fewer views (without just cramming it into the same page).

Answer (score 2):

Your question might be too broad but I would advise you to fully think this through.  A single page application would not just be one page with all functionality of your fifty views within it, it would probably require a complete change of application style.